# display only exact match jquery?

Tags: jquery

Im looking to do the opposite of what this jquery string does. It currently removes parent divs with an exact match but I need it to remove parent divs that do not contain an exact match. Basically not:contains but for an exact string of text.

```
$('.content').filter(function() {
    return $.text([this]) === 'TEXT';
}).parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to revert your condition to `not`

```
$('.content').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) !== 'TEXT'; }).parent().remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question only, just change condition in your jquery:

```
$('.content').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) !== 'TEXT'; }).parent().remove();
```

Try this out, hope it will give you what you want.